# Showing Top 5 Clients at a dashboard

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, nested-if

I want to build a dashboard where I can select a year and a application and want to have the top 5 clients shown up.

I build a example Sheet ofr showing:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13yk_SIsv52bZbskOkEzkz4f1aOMnb5yLDk2oo5BawXs/edit?usp=sharing

On the left side I have listed all top clients ob every year and per application.
On the right side I have a little selection tool and I want in the yellow marked area the correct data from the left side.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({""&A1:B\ C1:E}; 
 "select Col3,Col4,Col5 
  where 3=3 "&
 IF(I3="";;" and Col1 contains '"&I3&"'")&
 IF(I4="";;" and Col2 contains '"&I4&"'")&
 "order by Col5 desc 
  limit 5"; ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
= Query(A1:E; "Select C,D,E 
        where A contains '"&I3&"'
        and B contains '"&I4&"'
        Order by E Desc Limit 5 ")
```